# How to make a linked-list of different Classes?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, linked-list

I am relatively new to Java and to object oriented programming. I am learning about inheritance and OOP. I have this 1 class, lets say Bike, which has general information. Then I have these other classes, lets say Sports and Road, that extends Bike but I want to make a link list of these classes. So I would have one linked-list that contains both sports and road. But I am not sure how to go about and implement this. I know how to make a linked-list based on one class but not multiple ones. Thanks.

Comment: If `Sports` and `Road` are subclasses of `Bike`, then `List<Bike>` or `LinkedList<Bike>` can contain objects of any of those classes.  That's the nature of inheritance--an object of those types is also a `Bike`. (`Sports` is a horrible name for a type of bike, though.  `SportsBike` is much better, if that's what you mean.  Similarly `Road`, because I'd expect this class to represent a road, not a "road bike".)

Comment: @ajb sorry, thats what I meant. SportsBike and RoadBike. Isn't LinkedList<Bike> making a list? Its supposed to use things like *next and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a LL of the base class and add the elements you need.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ans{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    LinkedList<Parent> list = new LinkedList<Parent>();

    list.add(new ChildA());
    list.add(new ChildB());
    list.add(new Parent());

    for(Parent p: list)
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}

class Parent{
    public String toString(){
    return "I am a Parent";
    }
}

class ChildA extends Parent{
    public String toString(){
    return "I am a ChildA";
    }
}

class ChildB extends Parent{
    public String toString(){
    return "I am a ChildB";
    }
}
```

With an output

```
I am a ChildA
I am a ChildB
I am a Parent
```

Comment: Ahh. I see. I am learning Java after C so I was thinking I would have to connect them by next. Are all these standard functions in java?

Comment: @JMei Yes. You could implement your own LL but always prefer the standard implementation. More info at [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) and [for each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2).

Answer (score 0):

As Bike is the superclass, the List of Bike type can be used to store the object of its subclasses.Something like this

```
Road r1=new road();
Road r2=new road();
Sports s1=new Sports();
Sports s2=new Sports();
List<Bike> bikeType=new ArrayList<Bike>();
bikeType.add(r1);
bikeType.add(r2);
bikeType.add(s1);
bikeType.add(s2);
```